# How can I use jitter horizontally on boxplot outliers?

Tags: r, boxplot

I tried the following method from [Outliers for boxplot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43721/outliers-for-boxplot) and it worked well for me:

```
bar <- boxplot(foo,plot=FALSE)
boxplot(foo,outline=FALSE,ylim=c(min(c(bar$stats,bar$out)),max(c(bar$stats,bar$out))))
points(jitter(rep(1, length(bar$out))), bar$out)
```

What I need to do is use it with the boxplot parameter horizontal = TRUE.
My boxplot does work horizontally but the jittered outliers are absent.

Any suggestions as to how to make this work? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the `x` and `y` argument for `points()`. Note also how I simplified `ylim`.

```
set.seed(12345)
foo <- rnorm(1000)
bar <- boxplot(foo, plot = FALSE)
boxplot(foo, outline = FALSE,
        ylim = range(foo),
        horizontal = TRUE)
points(bar$out, jitter(rep(1, length(bar$out))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the multigroup setting, the following works:

```r
p <- boxplot(
    Sepal.Width ~ Species,
    data = iris,
    range = 0.5, # Just to get more outliers to show
    outline = FALSE,
    ylim = range(iris$Sepal.Width)
)
points(jitter(p$group, 0.1), p$out)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note the use of `p$group` to get the x-coordinate of the outliers (rather than `rep` as in previous answers).